# How to add field to notification laravel

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I am using laravel and use notification system

so I add a column "URL" to notifications table and want to store it in database but it does not work and really I do not know how can I add field and store in database

here is my notification class and notify when new comment submitted :

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class NewComment extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    private $details;


    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function __construct($details)
     {
       $this->details = $details;

     }


    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
      return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
      //
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
      return [
       'message' => $this->details['message'],
       'product' => $this->details['product'],
       'url' => 'test'
   ];

    }
}
```

here is controller

```
  $details = [
          'message' => 'یک نظر جدید برای محصول',
          'product' => $product->title
      ];
    $user->notify(new NewComment($details));
```

it gives me this error :

> General error: 1364 Field 'url' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 1):

The result returned from `toArray` (or `toDatabase`) method is stored as JSON in an existing column called `data`; So you don't need to (and better not to) add a new column to your existing table.

Just remove that column and it should work. later you can read that `url` from decoding the JSON from `data` column.

```
$data = json_decode(DB::table('notifications')->first()->data);
$url = $data->url;
```

Comment: While looking for how I could add another field to the table I came across your reply....and it wasn't until I read your reply that (of course!!) I realized I could just send my additional data through the DATA field (gasp!). Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewFox You're welcome :D